# mod-rewrite varying subdomain to php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect varying subdomains with a htaccess file.
An example:

URL: `http://varying-string.example.com/`

redirect.php:    `<?php echo $_GET['value']; ?>`

Output: `varying-string`

This is my try, but i doesnt work.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.redirect.episch.ch$ redirect.episch.ch/redirect.php?value=$1
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect or rewrite the url ?
If you want to redirect you should use *header("location:".$_GET['value'],true);*

Comment: Sorry, i want to rewirte the url. My fault.

Comment: Check this out http://serverfault.com/questions/203780/troubleshooting-a-htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-rewrite/203804#203804

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RewriteCondition` to catch the subdomain pattern.

The patterns you catch in rewrite conditions need to be referred as `%1` in the rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (\w*).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule domain.com /redirect.php?value=%1 [L,R=301]
```